# Unable to Receive SMS when Using BroadCast Receiver After Restarting Device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

i cant receive SMS after restarting device using Broadcast Receiver.
used try catch and found this error "attempt to get length of null array"

my Receiver Codes:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class ReceiveSMS extends BroadcastReceiver{


    private String number;
    private String text;
    WorksToDo worksToDo;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage smsMessage;
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] objects = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                    smsMessage=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) objects[i]);
                    number = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                    text = smsMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();
                }

                worksToDo = new WorksToDo(context, number, text);
                worksToDo.DoAll();


            }

        }catch (Exception ex){
            Log.i("Errrorrrrrrrrrr",ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

My Manifest Permissions and Receiver:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <receiver
                android:name=".ReceiveSMS">
                <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
                    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but when i open my app it works fine, what is wrong with this code?

or is there another way to receive sms after phone restart?

how is system sms app doing this? (i mean default sms app in device)

i have searched on Google and did not find any helpful answer to my problem.

Comment: There is not going to be a message attached to the `Intent`s for the `BOOT_COMPLETED` and `LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts. Why are you registering that Receiver for those actions?

Comment: @MikeM. I want my app receive sms after phone restart.

Comment: It already will with just the `SMS_RECEIVED` action, as long as you've launched your app at least once after installation, and requested the permission at runtime, as necessary.

Comment: @MikeM. Really? You say that there is no need to boot complete ? If i send sms to my device my receiver starts even after restarting and does not return null point on "objects.lengt"?

Comment: Yep, once the app is out of the _stopped_ state (which will happen when you launch it once after installation), that Receiver will be started up by the system whenever an SMS comes in. Those other actions are only for when you want to perform some task at those particular times, but once your SMS Receiver is enabled, it's good to go (unless you disable it programmatically, the user revokes the necessary permission, or your app is forcibly stopped).

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for question i will try it.❤

Comment: Ah wrong type *answer

Comment: @MikeM. Did not worked Receiver not started after restart.starts only with boot complete

Comment: Then you've got other problems.

Comment: @MikeM. Like what? Every thing is good but object.length is null even without for() it returns null like this ((byte[]) objects[0...n]).

Comment: Because there is no message attached to a `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. Why would there be? Why do you think that rebooting your device means you've received an SMS message?

Comment: @MikeM. I want my app and this receiver works after restart for some commands i send through sms. How is phones default message app works after restart? it is very important to receiver works after restart.

Comment: The default app has a `<receiver>` element listed in its manifest. Are you sure your Receiver isn't running when an SMS comes in after reboot? How are you determining that? Are you seeing the log print you have in the `catch`? You should put a log print at the top of `onReceive()`, too. What is `WorksToDo`? That looks somewhat suspicious, and is possibly failing there.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes im sure receiver is running otherwise try catch will not work. After receiving sms onReceive method starts until it comes on for() and then its crashe when try to get objects.lenght.
And WorksToDo is a class that gets number and text then compare them with numbers and commands in database that user saved. Every command has its own works,like "lock" to lock the screen.there is nothing suspicious. I tried to run mainactivity after restart in onreceive but did not started receiving sms

Comment: "Yes im sure receiver is running otherwise try catch will not work." - So the Receiver _does_ run when an SMS comes in after reboot? Then your problem is elsewhere. That array isn't going to be null for an `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast.

Comment: @MikeM. No it works fine until for (int i =0;i<objects.lenght;i++)
Without sending sms. Tried to remove Boot Complete but receiver didnt start.
Main problem is objects.lenght that returns null and for () not working after that

Comment: You _don't_ want that Receiver to run for the boot broadcasts. There's not going to be a message attached to those broadcasts, which is why you get the Exception. If the Receiver isn't running for new SMS after rebooting,  then something else is going on. Are you testing on an emulator, or a device? Some devices have additional restrictions on apps that prevent them from getting SMS in the background. Some also put apps back into the _stopped_ state when swiping from recents, so if you're doing that, see what happens if you rerun your app after booting.

Comment: @MikeM. Im testing on emulator and my phone, both results are same.
But after opening the app by my self it works fine without any problem.i tried libraries but they only work in activities.

Comment: Then I suspect that the problem is _WorksToDo_, which is what I meant by "suspicious" in my previous comment. What happens with the log print that you put at the top of `onReceive()`?

Comment: @MikeM. I removed WorksToDo too.only tried to receive sms.but like all the time,nothing changed. Can you please try this code without WorksToDo Class and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: If you removed _WorksToDo_, how do you know the Receiver isn't running? There's only three things you have to do to the basic project template to receive SMS: add the permission and Receiver to the manifest, create the Receiver class, and launch your app once. If it works for you at all, then it works, and rebooting is likely not the problem.

Comment: @MikeM. I know from the log that tells me "attempt to get length of null array" with WorksToDo or without it.

Comment: But when the broadcast is for an SMS, then that Exception isn't going to happen. That's why I suggested you put a log print at the top of `onReceive()`.

Comment: @MikeM. Top means top of the try? If yes so get logs from what? 
Or under variables?

Comment: As the very first line after `public void onReceive(...) {`. Log anything. A big string of asterisks, whatever. Just something you can see so you know it's reached there.

Comment: @MikeM. Tried to move all these lines in OnReceive method to another class and before calling class tried to open an activity.and it worked i mean activity started but sms part no.

Comment: Then that means that you are receiving SMS.

Comment: @MikeM. No i told activity started but sms part no. Let me tell you with an example , i moved all these lines from try to catch to another class named SmsReceive and its Main method then it will be like this
OnReceive(){

Intent intent1=new Intent(context,activity.class);
context.startactivity(intent1); 
//working

SmsReceive smsr=new SmsReceive(context,intent)
smsr.Main(); 
//not working
}

Comment: Yeah, I get that, but if that Receiver runs when an SMS comes in, then you _are_ receiving SMS. You're just not handling it correctly.

Comment: @MikeM. No if handling was not right then it will not work after opening the app my self. This is what happens.
After reboot completes,OnReceive method starts then it goes down until that for () but till now i didnt send any sms.and gives me an exception  that i wrote on my problem description. Please try it and you will see what im saying.

Comment: "No if handling was not right then it will not work after opening the app my self." - Wrong. It's very possible `WorksToDo` is failing while the app is not running because of how you've written it. "After reboot completes,OnReceive method starts..." - Why is `onReceive()` running at boot? Why haven't you removed those actions? They're pointless for an SMS Receiver, and they're not helping you to debug this. Depending on where you're testing, that crash might be putting the app back into the _stopped_ state, and preventing the Receiver from getting the broadcast you actually want.

Comment: @MikeM. I'll try it again without boot complete action and get logs line by line to see what happens.

Comment: @MikeM. Hi again
i did what you said and yes you were right no need to Boot Complete,i got sms text and sender number but i when i send them to WorksToDo class nothing happens.but after opening the app all things works good otherwise just i can receive sms just this.

Comment: @MikeM. all ok now the problem was ORM's context. Thank You for Help <3

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**

just changed **manifest** to :

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiveSMS">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

All works Fine